# bind() function is not executing at all, no output when testing it

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm learning socket programming in C. I have gotten my server to create a socket that was successful, but when I try to bind my socket to a port nothing happens. No error occurs and it is not successful. It's as if the `bind()` function is not even executing at all.

I've checked out the documentation on the `bind()` function [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) but there's no mention of why it won't execute at all. I've also tried searching through this site with no avail. 
I also tried following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIJGSQEipEE) tutorial from start to finish but the error (or lack thereof) still occurs.

Here is my full code leading up to the problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "include.h" 

int main() {

    // Descriptors. Used to check the status of functions such as socket, listen, bind etc.
    // If a descriptor is equal to 0, then everything is okay. Else, if they are equal to -1, something went wrong.
    int socketDescriptor, newSocketDescriptor = 1;

    // The process ID of a child process (the client) when a new one is spawned (the client connects).
    pid_t childPID;

    // A string to hold the commands being sent a received.
    char* commandBuffer = calloc(BUFFER_SIZE, sizeof(char));

    // A structure to hold information on the server address.
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    memset(&serverAddress, '\0', sizeof(serverAddress));

    // Fill in the server address information.
    // Set the address family to AF_INET, which specifies we will be using IPv4.
    // htons() takes the given int and converts it to the appropriate format. Used for port numbers.
    // inet_addr() takes the given string and converts it to the appropriate format. Used for IP addresses.
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    // A structure to hold information a client when a new one connects to this server.
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
    memset(&clientAddress, '\0', sizeof(clientAddress));

    // socklen_t defines the length of a socket structure. Need this for the accept() function.
    socklen_t addressSize;

    // Creating the socket.
    // AF_NET specifies that we will be using IPv4 addressing.
    // SOCK_STREAM specifies that we will be using TCP to communicate.
    socketDescriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (socketDescriptor < 0) {
        perror("ERROR CREATING SOCKET");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket created successfully.\n");

    // Binding to the specified port. 0 if everything is fine, -1 if there was an error.
    if (bind(socketDescriptor, (struct sockaddr*) & serverAddress, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0) {
        perror("ERROR BINDNING");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket bound to %s:%s.\n", serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr, serverAddress.sin_port);
```

The last `if` statement at the bottom is where the code fails. It should either print and error or print "Socket bound to 127.0.0.1:80" but neither happens. See an example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF95M.png).

I'm lost for what to do.

Comment: Your code looks incomplete; you haven't got a `PORT` defined.

Comment: You use `%s` in `printf()` format string but neither `s_addr` nor `sin_port` is a string. Your program probably crashes.

Comment: @danadam I have my code to format those values properly and that fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server socket won't show up in a netstat listing unless you call `listen` after binding the socket.

Also, you're using the `%s` format specifier in your `printf` after the `bind` call on `serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr` and `serverAddress.sin_port`.  These are not strings but integers.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and is likely causing your program to crash.  Using the correct format specifier such as `%d` or `%x` will fix this.

```
if (bind(socketDescriptor, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0) {
    perror("ERROR BINDNING");
    exit(1);
}
else
    // use %x to print instead
    printf("Socket bound to %x:%x.\n", serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr, serverAddress.sin_port);

if (listen(socketDescriptor, 3) < 0) {
    perror("listen failed");
} else {
    printf("socket is listening\n");
}
```

Comment: This is the answer, thank you very much! I changed the last line to `printf("Socket bound to %s:%d.\n", inet_ntoa(serverAddress.sin_addr, ntohs(serverAddress.sin_port));` and it worked. I was not converting those values properly